# Capybara, Selenium, Jupyter Notebook: filling code cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, jupyter-notebook

I want to use Capybara to input text into a Jupyter Notebook cell. Clicking the element and using 'send_keys' does not work, although the cursor ends up in the right location: `find(".input").click.send_keys("hello")`

Is there a way to simulate pressing keys without selecting an element? `find("body").send_keys("hello")` also does not produce any text

Edit: I found out that the Jupyter Notebook uses CodeMirror. CodeMirror uses a hidden `<textarea>` field somehow, so that would explain why Selenium refused to find the input.

My current workaround is to find the first CodeMirror editor and use the `setValue` function on it: `execute_script("var editor = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror; editor.setValue('this is the input')")`

Comment: The key events have to be sent to some element (that element could be the body element if wanted).  Do you have to click on an element before typing? Can you show the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoided the workaround by using Selenium's action builder. Find the desired element and get its native selenium representation:

`el_native = first('.input').native`

Then, use the action builder to click into the element and send keys:

`page.driver.browser.action.click(el_native).send_keys("hello").perform`